# How would i implement an infinite scroll in my DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So i have JSON object that i am reading through which looks like

> {data:[Object,Object.....]}

Currently i am using the

> getJSON

method to extract that data. 
Say there are around 1600 sets of Objects in this array.

Currently  when i load the page it takes a few seconds as it is parsing all those objects. How would i go about with the logic of presenting the first hundred objects and then the next hundred and so on. Without any lags

Any feedback would be appreciated

```
  $.getJSON('products.json', function (pdata) {
          for(var i =0; i < pdata.data.length; i++) {
              getInformation(pdata.data[i]);
          }

  function getInformation(obj){
          console.log(obj);

          var $ul = $('<ul>').addClass('view').appendTo('body');

          for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
              var $list = $('<li>').appendTo($ul);
              var $image = $('<img>').appendTo($list);
              var $content = $('<div>').appendTo($list);
              var $productName = $('<div>').appendTo($content);
              var $price = $('<div>').appendTo($content);

              $image.attr({src: obj.imageUrl,
               width: '200px',
               height: '200px'
              });

              $content.addClass('content');
              $productName.addClass('productName');
              $price.addClass('price');

              $productName.html(obj.fullName);
              $price.html('Price: '+ obj.price);
          }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scroll to 100px before bottom will execute you code with inserting data

```
window.bInsertingJSON = false;
window.onscroll = function(){
    if(window.pageYOffset >= (document.body.scrollHeight-document.body.clientHeight - 100) && !window.bInsertingJSON) {
        // add block flag
        window.bInsertingJSON = true;
        // here's your code
        // don't forget to reset flag on the end of JSON parsing/inserting
    }
}
```

you getInformation function is very heavy for DOM... to much appends and changes, easy use

```
function getInformation(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    var sHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        sHTMl += "<li>";
        sHTMl += "<img src='" + obj.imageUrl + "' style='width:200px;height:200px'/>";
        sHTMl += "<div class='content'><div>";
        sHTMl += "<div class='productName'>" + obj.fullName + "<div>";
        sHTMl += "<div class='price'>Price: " + obj.price + "</div>";
        sHTMl += "</li>";
    }
    $("<ul class='view'>"+sHTML+"</ul>").appendTo(body);
    // and I'll give a second for implement it
    setTimeout(function(){window.bInsertingJSON = false;},1000);
}
```

As I see you use jQuery. Well done. Let's change event handler to jQuery.
First, explain about flag. Use this for block event processing till you insert new Objects.

let's start

You do not need to define it as we use global variable, set it to false on start

```
window.bInsertingJSON = false;
```

for block inserting on scroll up, let's define variable

```
window.nPrevScroll = 0;
```

on window ready

$(function(){

next let's define event handle for scroll

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(){
```

here we need to write condition for insert, if scroll down (100 is constant for 100px in bottom)

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > window.prevScroll
```

and compare scroll position and window.height

```
&& $(window).scrollTop() + $("body").outerHeight() + 100 >= $(document).outerHeight()
```

and flag for stop event processing until insert DOM elements

```
&& !window.bInsertingJSON) {
```

set flag for stop processing

```
window.bInsertingJSON = true;
```

and call you ajax request

```
$.getJSON('products.json', function (pdata) {
    for(var i =0; i < pdata.data.length; i++) {
        getInformation(pdata.data[i]);
    }
});
```

end of condition

```
}
```

end of event handler

```
});
```

Now, define you processing function

```
function getInformation(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    var sHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        sHTMl += "<li>";
        sHTMl += "<img src='" + obj.imageUrl + "' style='width:200px;height:200px'/>";
        sHTMl += "<div class='content'><div>";
        sHTMl += "<div class='productName'>" + obj.fullName + "<div>";
        sHTMl += "<div class='price'>Price: " + obj.price + "</div>";
        sHTMl += "</li>";
    }
    $("<ul class='view'>"+sHTML+"</ul>").appendTo(body);
```

And here you can reset flag for processing. I recommend add 1 sec pause for inserting in DOM finished and window size changed

```
    setTimeout(function(){window.bInsertingJSON = false;},1000);
}
```

As I see in this case you'll block unneeded JSON parsing calls.

Now, this is complete code without comments

```
window.bInsertingJSON = false;
    window.nPrevScroll = 0;
$(function(){    
    $(window).on("scroll", function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > window.prevScroll
            && $(window).scrollTop() + $("body").outerHeight() + 100 >= $(document).outerHeight()
            && !window.bInsertingJSON) {
            window.bInsertingJSON = true;
            $.getJSON('products.json', function (pdata) {
                for(var i =0; i < pdata.data.length; i++) {
                    getInformation(pdata.data[i]);
                }
            });
        }
        window.nPrevScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    });

});

function getInformation(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    var sHTML = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        sHTMl += "<li>";
        sHTMl += "<img src='" + obj.imageUrl + "' style='width:200px;height:200px'/>";
        sHTMl += "<div class='content'><div>";
        sHTMl += "<div class='productName'>" + obj.fullName + "<div>";
        sHTMl += "<div class='price'>Price: " + obj.price + "</div>";
        sHTMl += "</li>";
    }
    $("<ul class='view'>"+sHTML+"</ul>").appendTo(body);

    setTimeout(function(){window.bInsertingJSON = false;},1000);
}
```

Comment: i am bit confused, after checking the offset and setting the flag to true, i still have loop through the data . Could you provide a bit of more explanation, thnxs for the response

Comment: I guess it's important when you reset flag to false. I checked code twice and it works correct.

For test, I added line 
**console.log('test');
setTimeout(function(){window.bInsertingJSON = false;},3000);**
and it stopped to work for 3 sec.
Could you show me you code for add DOM elements from json?

Comment: Yeah i added the code in the question where i access the json and add to the DOM

Comment: It's very heavy code for DOM as you have a lot of inserting and modifications of DOM. use simple

Comment: answer in my 1st comment

Comment: So getInformation should be invoked after the flag is set to true?

Comment: I am still confused on the part where even after refactoring the DOM, it takes a while for the content to be loaded

Comment: is it suppose to be $(window).scrollTop() > window.nPrevScroll than $(window).scrollTop() > window.prevScroll

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I would just use a framework that does this for you, like datatables or angular.

However, if you implemented some kind of logic and you think your unique solution is the best solution, all you have to do is maintain your data list in a global object and paginate it, only appending the "next 10" when a user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

Something along the lines of:

```
var data = [];
var page = 0;
function loadNext(int number){
    page++;
    RenderNext(data.splice(page-1 * size, page * size);
}
```

Where RenderNext() is your previously existing code that parses out all records from your argument.