# JSON Object (how to not load the entire object on DOM initially)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So i am reading a local json file that consist of {[Object,Object,Object.....]}
I am using the

```
 $.getJSON('products.json', function (pdata) {
              for (var i = 0; i < pdata.data.length; i++) {
                  AppendtoDom(pdata.data[i]);

              }
```

The above code reads the json objects and appends to the DOM, but i want to initially load only 100 objects at a time and on scroll keep appending.

Say there are around 1200 objects. How do i go about this?

My implementaion so far

```
  $(function(){
      loadData();
  });

  function loadData(){
      $.getJSON('products.json', function (pdata) {
          var i = 0;
              function addtoDom(num){
                  var limit = Math.min(i + num, pdata.data.length);
                  for(; i < limit; i++){
                      getInformation(pdata.data[i]);
                  }
              }
              addtoDom(100);
          $('.content').jscroll({
              callback: addtoDom(100)
          });
      });
  }

  function getInformation(obj){
         var content = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
              content += '<li>';
              content += "<img src='" + obj.imageUrl + "' style='width:200px;height:200px'/>";
              content += '<div class="productName">' + obj.fullName + "</div>";
              content += '<div class="price">Price: ' + obj.price + "</div>";
              content +=  '</li>';
          }
      $("<ul class= 'view'>" + content + "</ul>").appendTo('.content');


  }
```

Similar question i asked in [How would i implement an infinite scroll in my DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722640/how-would-i-implement-an-infinite-scroll-in-my-dom/28723128?noredirect=1#comment45743996_28723128)

Comment: What is `AppendtoDom` defined as?

Comment: first you have to identify your scroll activity, then keep a sort of mark where to start and stop, usually you allow to load all in the DOM and just hide those you don't want to show yet,

Comment: @jsve that function just takes in the obj as a param and uses the properties on the obj and assign it to the necessary elements

Comment: @paulpolo could i use jscroll plugin? How do you go about hiding part of the logic

Comment: @user3750842, yes you can use a plugin, that uses lazy load, which improves performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put all the objects you get back from the Ajax call into a persistent variable, add the first 100 to the DOM, keep a counter of how many you've added so far and then upon scrolling to a certain point, add another 100, add another 100 and so on.

```
$.getJSON('products.json', function (pdata) {
     var i = 0;

     function addMore(num) {
         var limit = Math.min(i + num, pdata.data.length);
         for (; i < limit; i++) {
              AppendtoDom(pdata.data[i]);
         }
     }

     // add the first 100
     addMore(100);

     // then set up whatever scroll detection you want here and 
     // when you decide that it has scrolled enough to add some more
     // you just call addMore(100) again

});
```

---

In your specific implementation of the above idea, you have an implementation mistake.  You have to pass a function reference for the callback so change this:

```
      $('.content').jscroll({
          callback: addtoDom(100)
      });
```

to this:

```
      $('.content').jscroll({
          callback: function() {addtoDom(100);}
      });
```

Comment: +1 but just want to add that instead of individually adding 100 items to the DOM, it would be more performant to merge these 100 items into 1 and then make 1 DOM modification

Comment: thnxs for the explanation instead of calling addMore(100) manually how would one do that?

Comment: @jasonscript - For max performance, yes you would want to do one DOM operation (perhaps using a fragment), but not sure the extra code would be needed or even noticed by the user here because of the indeterminate timing (from the user's point of view) that more are added.

Comment: @user3750842 - are you asking how you detect scrolling?  If so, you'd have to disclose your HTML and explain what scroll position you're trying to detect (e.g. logically when do you want to trigger the adding of more items)?  Also, please explain why you don't just add them all to the DOM initially since you've already retrieved them all from the server.

Comment: @jfriend00 i am trying to use jscroll() on the parent container, my aim is to have only 100 in a DOM at once and on scroll add another 100

Comment: @user3750842 - so in the jscroll callback that is calls to add more content, you would call `addMore(100)`.  If you want further help, you need to ask something more specific.

Comment: @jfriend00 i did try calling the addMore() in the jscroll(function(){...}) but it doesnt load up the next 100

Comment: @user3750842 - then something is wrong with your implementation.  There is nothing we can do to help on that score if you don't show us the actual code that you're using.

Comment: @jfriend00 i have added my implementation in the original post

Comment: @jfriend00 i have gone with your logic of getting the data

Comment: @user3750842 - See what I added to the end of my answer to fix your implementation mistake.  If that still doesn't fix it, then put a `console.log("callback called")` inside the callback function to see if it is actually getting called or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your JSON to a variable and dynamically render them as needed.

```js
var json;
$.getJSON('products.json', function (pdata) {
  JSON = pdata;
};

// Scheduling logic
        AppendtoDom(json[i]);
```